# Using Python 2 struct.pack with variable size array as argument

Tags: python

I need to pack variable length array using the struct.pack in Python 2.4.3, and tips?

The array datavalues needs to be n in length and I wish to use as the last argument in the pack with listing each element.

```
datavalues = array("i",[20, 40, 60])
data = conn.recv(1024)
print 'Connect by', addr
print 'nice try'
sys.stdout.write(hexdump(data))
recvStruct = '>hhhBBhh'
recvStructSize = struct.calcsize(recvStruct)
recvFormat = '%s%dx' % (recvStruct, len(data) - recvStructSize)
TransID , ProtoColID, PacketLength, UnitID, FC, StartAddress, RegisterCount = struct.unpack(recvFormat, data)
datatranStruct = '>hhhBBBhhh'
datatranStructSize = struct.calcsize(datatranStruct)
datatranFormat = '%s%dx' % (datatranStruct, 10 + (2*RegisterCount) - datatranStructSize)
print 'datatranFormat ',datatranFormat
print TransID, ProtoColID, PacketLength, UnitID
print  FC, StartAddress, RegisterCount
# I want to just say datavalues in the next line, I know I need to fix the format statement when using n values
datatran = struct.pack(datatranFormat, TransID , ProtoColID, PacketLength+(2*RegisterCount), UnitID, FC, 2*RegisterCount, datavalues[0], datavalues[1], datavalues[2])
conn.sendall(datatran)
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the `tostring()` method?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Python and working in an embedded system. you say I convert this integer array to a string that is actually a list of integers from the array?

Comment: At least pretend to look at the documentation.

Comment: I am sorry you believe this, but I actually started out with tostring and byte array. I had no success getting it to work, I maybe new to python but I program 30 years in C. I am in an embedded system with a very old Python interpreter, I need to be highly accurate because and edit and test takes 30 minutes. I even get surprised that the sockets library did not exist. So please forgive me for asking. I have not been able to understand all the converstions happening in this pack statement easily.